# Reading superscript excel text with Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, superscript

I have an Excel worksheet with some Text cells that contains a superscript and an hyperlink. The hyperlink is simple to extract but i could't extract the superscript :/, the program detects it like plain text. "8^2 --> 82". 
[image: My Excel with superscript]

The code

```
excel = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("filename.xlsx"));
        Sheet hoja = excel.getSheetAt(4);
        List<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> links = new ArrayList<String>();

        //recorrido
        Iterator<Row> filas = hoja.rowIterator();
        while (filas.hasNext()) {
            Row fila = filas.next();
            Iterator<Cell> celdas = fila.cellIterator();
            while (celdas.hasNext()) {
                Cell celda = celdas.next();
                System.out.print(celda.toString() + " || ");
                datos.add(String.valueOf(celda));
                Hyperlink linkAddress = celda.getHyperlink();
                if (linkAddress != null) {
                    links.add(linkAddress.getAddress());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

The code shows how i'm whatching the cell contain, just the code probe.

I'm using Apache POI 3.14.

Comment: Did you check [this similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499918/reading-superscript-and-subscript-in-excel-cell-using-apache-poi-in-java)?

Comment: Yes! Actually i just solved the problem with that thread! I was looking for the answer yesterdey for hours, including in stockoverflow but nope. But when i posted the question, a few minutes later i found the answer! Thanks. Do you know how to check the question "solved"?

Comment: To mark the question as solved, you can post the code that worked for you as an answer and accept that answer.

Comment: Thanks you for your fast answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using some RichTextString properties. I created two methods to extract the value and the superscript of the Cell's RichTextString.
To obtain the value we may need to iterate and to concatenate all the String content, except the last one. The last one is always the full superscript.

```
private static String getValue(XSSFRichTextString cellContent){
    String value = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < cellContent.numFormattingRuns() - 1; i++) {
        int lenVal = cellContent.getLengthOfFormattingRun(i);
        int iVal = cellContent.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
        value += cellContent.toString().substring(iVal, lenVal + iVal);
    }
    return value;
}
private static String getSuperScript(XSSFRichTextString cellContent) {
    int lenSuper = cellContent.getLengthOfFormattingRun(cellContent.numFormattingRuns() - 1);
    int iSuper = cellContent.getIndexOfFormattingRun(cellContent.numFormattingRuns() - 1);
    return cellContent.toString().substring(iSuper, lenSuper + iSuper);
}
```

It obtains from 8^1 --> value=8, superScript=1 for example.
Or from "superscript example ^ A,B" --> value="superscript example", superScript="A,B".

Comment: This works specially only for your exact use case. You have told, you have gotten this from an SO answer. Can you please provide a link to that answer? Maybe it will be more general.

Comment: Here you are: [link](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/ExcelExtractor.java)